# Android V7 Support Library Popup Menu

Tags: android, android-support-library

I'm trying to implement a PopupMenu with the Support V7 Library. All compiles fine but when I try to call:

```
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
    popup.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE,MENU_SHARE_A,1,R.string.A);
    popup.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE,MENU_SHARE_B,2,R.string.B);
    popup.show();
```

an error occurs on call:

> 07-31 17:23:53.365: E/AndroidRuntime(14128):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #17: You must supply
>   a layout_height attribute.

Which refers I think to "abc_popup_menu_item_layout.xml" with this element:

```
<android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ListMenuItemView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight"
        android:minWidth="196dip"
        android:paddingRight="16dip">
```

Is this is a bug or do I do something wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You might want to check if you have an appropriate theme specified in your manifest file:

```
<application ... android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
```

Comment: For me it was the theme.  I'm hitting problems in a unit test that tries to open the menu.  Somehow the theme was not being set during the test and I had to set it manually using context.setTheme(...);

Answer (score 18):

```
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
```

what's "this" refer to ? the first parameter must be a context like Activity, not ApplicationContext!!

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. It's the context that has to match!

Comment: I was passing an application context instead an activity context too. This answer was a life saver. I was creating the `PopupMenu` from an Adapter which populated a `Fragment`'s `ListView` and accidentally passed application context to that adapter, resulting in passing it to th e `PopupMenu` constructor too....Remember kids your `Context` matters!!

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your Activity inside your **manifest.xml**

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your layout file "abc_popup_menu_item_layout.xml" already shows a height defined.

Either "?attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight" is something from a different theme or library (such as ActionBarSherlock), or the error is coming from a different layout file.

Also, if you swap out "?attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight" for something like "60dp" does the error go away?

Answer (score 0):

@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light resovled the problem for me. @style/Theme.AppCompat is a dark theme, it deosn't fit my applicatoin.

Answer (score 0):

Also check if there is another style that is applied within each activities in manifest.xml. This will override Theme.AppCompat in application tag.