# PopupMenu from supportlibrary

Tags: android, android-support-library

Hey I'm getting the following error when trying to open a popupmenu from my view:

```
10-15 11:43:27.421: E/AndroidRuntime(7825): java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #17: You must supply a layout_height attribute.
```

My code is here :

```
OnClickListener thirdButtonListener = new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(activity,v);
                popup.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, BottomBarView.ORDER_OVERVIEW, 1, R.string.app_order_overview);
                popup.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, BottomBarView.SUPPLIERS, 2, R.string.app_suppliers);
                popup.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, BottomBarView.INVOICES, 3, R.string.app_invoice);
                popup.show();
            }
        };
```

It seems to be some ?attr values from the support library that isn't being set...

like this: `android:layout_height="?attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight"` but not sure.
Any suggestions ?

Comment: You can find the answer here at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975002/android-v7-support-library-popup-menu/18154001#18154001?newreg=f836bf03893a4b429976701aef77c63d

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this :

`android:layout_height:"wrap_content"` to button where you click to open popup menu.

remove this : 
`android:layout_height="?attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight"` 
from :

```
android:layout_height:"wrap_content"
```

Comment: And how would I do that since the ?attr is in the support library...?

Answer (score 1):

Please try apply @style/Theme.AppCompat, Theme.AppCompat.Light or Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar to your activity. See also [Android V7 Support Library Popup Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975002/android-v7-support-library-popup-menu)