# Custom style for Popup menu compatible back port in Android

Tags: android, android-support-library

I want to create a popup menu like [this link](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/1267), but used for my view instead of action bar.
I tried to use [android support library v7](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html) to support old devices. The problem is I got `RuntimeException: You must supply a layout_height attribute` when creating back port Popup menu. 
Here is my snippet code:

```
// use support lib 
import android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu;

button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // Creating the instance of PopupMenu
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, button);
    // Inflating the Popup using xml file
    popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu,
    popup.getMenu());

    // registering popup with OnMenuItemClickListener
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
            "You Clicked : " + item.getTitle(),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    });

    popup.show();
}
});
```

The logcat error:

```
    03-18 16:39:53.005: E/AndroidRuntime(28936): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    03-18 16:39:53.005: E/AndroidRuntime(28936): java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #17: You must supply a layout_height attribute.
    03-18 16:39:53.005: E/AndroidRuntime(28936):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:492)
    03-18 16:39:53.005: E/AndroidRuntime(28936):    at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:6057)
    03-18 16:39:53.005: E/AndroidRuntime(28936):    at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:6225)
    03-18 16:39:53.005: E/AndroidRuntime(28936):    at android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(FrameLayout.java:610)
    03-18 16:39:53.005: E/AndroidRuntime(28936):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.generateLayoutParams(FrameLayout.java:554)
    03-18 16:39:53.005: E/AndroidRuntime(28936):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.generateLayoutParams(FrameLayout.java:56)
    03-18 16:39:53.005: E/AndroidRuntime(28936):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:486)
    03-18 16:39:53.005: E/AndroidRuntime(28936):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
    03-18 16:39:53.005: E/AndroidRuntime(28936):    at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper$MenuAdapter.getView(MenuPopupHelper.java:335)
    03-18 16:39:53.005: E/AndroidRuntime(28936):    at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.measureContentWidth(MenuPopupHelper.java:190)
    03-18 16:39:53.005: E/AndroidRuntime(28936):    at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.tryShow(MenuPopupHelper.java:128)
    03-18 16:39:53.005: E/AndroidRuntime(28936):    at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.show(MenuPopupHelper.java:102)
    03-18 16:39:53.005: E/AndroidRuntime(28936):    at android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu.show(PopupMenu.java:108)
    03-18 16:39:53.005: E/AndroidRuntime(28936):    at com.javatpoint.popupmenu.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:41)
```

How can I solve this bug and how can I apply custom style for Popup Menu with support library?

**Update**: by changing my theme to `Theme.AppCompat` according [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22302482/719212), this bug is fixed. But I still don't know how to custom style for Popup Menu.
Any help would be appreciated!